# A categorical characterization of the lexicographic order

Tags: order-theory, ct.category-theory

In $Pos$ (the category of partial ordered sets and order preserving maps) there is the categorical product of two objects, but on the set product there is (naturally) also the lexicographic order. I ask:

has this latter some kind of categorical universal property? Or a categorical (external) characterization?

Comment: I believe it's normally spelled "lexicographic"

Comment: Notice that the lexicographic order depends on which poset you choose to list first.  Thus if it is to satisfy a universal property, this property must also depend on the order of the two posets.

Comment: Manny Reyes: sure, but isnt essential, anyway consider the "first" (the primary for the lexicographic order) as the one on the left.  

Comment: I seems resolved it, need preorders: the lexicographic preorder $x\times_l y$ is the universal object for the preorders $a$ by two morphism $f: a\to x,\ g: a\to |y|$ (where $|y|$ is the underling set of $y$ (caotic preorder)) plus a third  morphism $h: a'\to y$ (where $a'$=*"pullback of $f$ by $\Delta_x\to x$"*) such that $\eta\circ h=g\circ \alpha$ where $\alpha: a'\to a,\ \eta: y\to |y|$ naturals 

Comment: @Manny - it may be a non-symmetric monoidal structure on $Pos$, but this would preclude there being a definition via a universal property. Alternatively, since $Pos$ is a 2-category, it might be some sort of a lax 2-limit. In that case, the order _is_ important, unlike limits in a 1-category.

Comment: @Buschi - you are allowed to add an answer to your own question. You get more space and can format things better that way ;)

Answer (score 3):

As David Roberts said, I post the  solution for preorders:

for two preorders $(X,\leq),\ (Y,\leq)$,  let $(X,\leq)\times_l(Y,\leq)$ the lexicographic preorder (priority to the first factor  $(X,\leq)$).

We observe that a  preorder morphism $(A,\leq)\to (X,\leq)\times_l (Y,\leq)$  is a set map  $(f, g): A\to X\times Y$ such that $f: (A,\leq)\to (X,\leq)$ is a preorder morphism, and $g: A\to Y$ a set map (we can view it as a morphism $g: (A,\leq)\to ch(Y)$ where $ch(Y)$ is the chaotic preorder on the set $Y$ (dont exists the functorial analogy for orders)) and If $a\leq a'$ and $f(a)=f(a')$ then we have $g(a)\leq g(a')$.

Reciprocally if we have the data maked as: a couple of morphisms like $f: (A,\leq)\to (X,\leq)$, $g: (A,\leq)\to ch(Y)$ such that *"If $a\leq a'$ and $f(a)=f(a')$ then we have $g(a)\leq g(a')$"*, then we get the (unique) morphisms  $(f, g): (A,\leq)\to (X,\leq)\times_l (Y,\leq)$.

Let $U: Preord\to Set$ the forgetfull functor from the preorders to sets category, this has a right adjoint funtor $Ch: Set\to Preord$ (the chaotic preorder), now the phrase *"$a\leq a'$ and $f(a)=f(a')$"* is described by the categorical  relation  $r_l: R_A(\leq)\cap P\subset A\times A$ where $R_A(\leq)$ is the  preorder relation on $A$ and $P$ the pullback of $f\times f$ by the diagonal morphism $\Delta_X\subset X\times X$. Then $X\times_lY$ is universal (initial) for the objects $A$ with two morphisms $f: A\to X$, $g: A\to Ch(U(Y,\leq))$ such that $(g\times g)\circ r_l: R_A(\leq)\cap P\to Y\times Y $ as a (unique) factorization to the preorder relation  $R_Y(\leq)\subset Y\times Y$ of  $(Y,\leq)$.

now I realized it was just an easy exercise in translation of categorical logic, that is from the the formula to  categorical diagrams.