# On the universal property of the lexicographic order, again

Tags: ct.category-theory

I need to improve [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/82967/a-categorical-characterization-of-the-lexicographic-order) description of the lexicographic order on a product $P\times Q$ of two posets, unraveling its universal property (if any).

In the other thread it is claimed (without further comment) that $P\times_\text{lex}Q$ might be some sort of 2-categorical limit (lax, since the construction is non symmetric). This is what I would like to see.

Some sparse considerations:

1. If $P\times_\text{lex}Q$ was a comma object of two functors $P\to S\leftarrow Q$ then $P\times_\text{lex}Q$ would have a functor to $Q$; but this doesn't exist in general.
2. Maybe $P\times_\text{lex}Q$ arises as a funny tensor product of posets seen as categories; but whereas we know that there are exactly two structures of symmetric monoidal closed category on $\bf Cat$, how many such *nonsymmetric* structures are there?
3. Even if there is no projection $P\times_\text{lex}Q \to Q$, there is always $P\times_\text{lex}Q \to P$; moreover each fiber of this functor is precisely $Q$. This is a fibration with some properties: is this an instance of a construction on $\bf Cat$, restricted to posets?

Comment: Random idea: take the constant diagram P-->Cat on Q, and do the Grothendieck construction?

Comment: Even in its most lax formulation, such a category of elements doesn't seem to work: if you consider $c_Q : P \to Cat$ constant, then its category of elements has objects $P\times Q$ (correct) but morphisms $(p,q)\le (p',q')$ those $p\le p'$ such that there is also $q\le q'$.

Comment: What I need is instead soomething that says "$(p,q)\le (p',q')$ is $p\lneq p'$ (and no condition on $q$) or $p=p'$ and $q\le q'$"

Comment: I'm almost sure that $P\times_\text{lex}Q$ can't be a category of elements. So the question is even more open :)